# Keep getting: ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError in PartiesController#create?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, database-design, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I keep getting ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError in PartiesController#create:

I have three models: Party, Products, Traits.

```
  class Party < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :products
  end

  class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :party
  has_many :traits
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :traits
  end

  class Trait < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  end
```

The party form:

```
  <%= form_for(@party) do |f| %>
  <% if @party.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
  <h2><%= pluralize(@party.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this party from being    
  saved:</h2>

  <ul>
  <% @party.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
  <li><%= msg %></li>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
  </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
  <%= f.label :name %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <table> 
  <%= f.fields_for :products do |builder| %>

  <tr> 
  <td> <%= builder.label :shirt, "Shirt " %> </td>
  <td> <%= builder.text_field :shirt %> </td>

  <%= f.fields_for :traits do |builder| %>
  <td><%= builder.label :color, "Color" %></td>
  <td><%= builder.text_field :color %></td>
  <td><%= builder.label :quantity, "Quantity" %></td>
  <td><%= builder.number_field :quantity %></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><%= builder.label :pants, "Pants " %></td>
  <td><%= builder.text_field :pants %></td>
  <td><%= builder.label :color, "Color" %></td>
  <td><%= builder.text_field :color %></td>
  <td><%= builder.label :quantity, "Quantity" %></td>
  <td><%= builder.number_field :quantity %></td>
  </tr>
  <% end %>
  <% end %> 
  </table>
  <div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
  <% end %>
```

The parties controller:

```
  class PartiesController < ApplicationController
  def new
  @party = Party.new
1.times do
product = @party.products.build
2.times {product.traits.build}
  end
  end

  def create
  @party = Party.new(params[:party])

  respond_to do |format|
  if @party.save
    format.html { redirect_to @party, notice: 'Party was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render json: @party, status: :created, location: @party }
  else
    format.html { render action: "new" }
    format.json { render json: @party.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
  end
  end
```

The show page:
      <%= notice %>

```
  This is <%= @party.name %>'s registry:
  <table>
  <% for product in @party.products %>
  <tr>  
  <td>Shirt</td>
  <td> <%= product.shirt %> </td>
  <% for trait in @product.traits %>
  <td>Color</td>
  <td> <%= trait.color %> </td>
  <td>Quantity</td>
  <td> <%= trait.quantity %> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>Pants</td>
  <td> <%= product.pants %> </td>
  <td>Color</td>
  <td> <%= trait.color %> </td>
  <td>Quantity</td>
  <td> <%= trait.quantity %> </td>
  </tr>
  <% end %> 
  </table>

  <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_party_path(@party) %> |
  <%= link_to 'Back', parties_path %>
  <% end %>
```

I've tried everything. What am I missing? Thanks people!

Comment: The logs does not say what exactly attribute is unknown? eg: `ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute: pants)`

Comment: No. The very first line after the error code. The rest of the log is not needed. And log of POST request will be helpful too (it is must be before error log).

Comment: Ok, its "unknown attribute: traits" - thats it! And the POST request is - {"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"jDeOGA+RRmyQgMlcg5flidP/OeP5Kfo2YBuMfeALolY=",
 "party"=>{"name"=>"",
 "products_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"shirt"=>""}},
 "traits"=>{"color"=>"",
 "quantity"=>"",
 "pants"=>""}},
 "commit"=>"Create Party"}

Comment: Sorry that's probably not the POST request => where can I find that?

Answer (score 4):

So the params[:party] hash probably contains elements from the form that are not attributes of Party. To debug, try:

```
def create
  @party = Party.new(:name => params[:party][:name])
```

I think the real complication is that Traits are nested under Products which are nested under Party. This is why the `fields_for` method for Traits needs to be `builder.fields_for :traits do |traits_fields|' (although I think you *could* put "builder" instead of "traits_fields".

Then for all of the traits fields, use `<%= traits_fields.label :pants, "Pants " %>`

Then it should work the way you had it:

```
def create
  @party = Party.new(params[:party])
```

Comment: Yes, but that relates to the new controller, right? I added the create controller.

Comment: Sorry, I think all that does is cancel the everything except name?

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Answer (score 2):

The error in parameter `traits`, when it should be `"products_attributes"=>{"traits_attributes" => ...`.

Try this: `<%= builder.fields_for :traits do |traits_fields| %>` instead of: `<%= f.fields_for :traits do |builder| %>`

Comment: Ok, I had to change all the builders to trait_fields and badaboom it worked. If you don't mind, why, I don't understand, in the Rails Cast they didn't have to do it. I would love to understand why. Also, is there any other way to structure the new controller? And lastly how did you figure it out? Thanks, I owe you man. Cheers. Erin

Comment: @Erin Walker, you are welcome. I do not want to be boring, I just want to give advice that might help. I can answer these questions, but they will not help, because I see that you are not very well understand about what you use. Try to learn about the requests, CRUD, something more simple. Learn how to debug the application. About the questions: in this case I would use simply cocoon (https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon), in railscasts there was  not third level of nesting, I found an error by looking at the logs.

Comment: Thanks I will - have read Agile Rails, Ruby on Rails Tut and Zombie for Rails 1 and 2 twice, but will hopefully get there soon.